# Ruby on Rails Rake test - Expected 762146111 to match 762146111

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake-test

My test fail on:

```
assert_match @post.user_id, @user.id
```

with strange error:

```
Expected 762146111 to match 762146111.
```

I have tried to use with and w/o Integer() in creation and/or on match steps

Comment: why not `assert_equal`? `assert_match` is expecting the first argument to be a regex using `=~`. e.g. `123 == 123 #=> true` but `123 =~ 123 #=> nil`. BTW `nil` response comes from the `Object` implementation [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-3D-7E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky).

It should be:

```
assert_equal @post.user_id, @user.id
```